# inform typescript that an exception has been thrown from a function

Tags: typescript

I have this code which behaves the way I would expect:

```
if (!groupRef) {
  throw new Error('a group ref is required to get dimenstions in ActivityLabel');
}


const bBox = groupRef.current.getBBox();
```

groupRef can be undefined but check for its existence in the if expression satisfies typescript to not throw a compiler error `Object is possibly 'undefined'`

I also use [invariant](https://github.com/zertosh/invariant) which asserts the first argument is truthy or throws an exception.

But typescript does not pick up that this should ensure its existence:

```
invariant(!!groupRef, 'a group ref is required to get dimenstions in ActivityLabel');

const bBox = groupRef.current.getBBox();
```

The type definition for invariant is this:

```
declare let invariant:invariant.InvariantStatic;

export = invariant;
export as namespace invariant;

declare namespace invariant {
  interface InvariantStatic {
    (testValue:any, format?:string, ...extra:any[]):void;
  }
}
```

It states that the function returns void.

Is there anyway I have the invariant type definition tell typescript in the same way as the more verbose `throw` code?

Comment: There is no type assertion syntax in typescript. Only type-guards, and type-guards require an `if` to be effective. (I believe there is a suggestion to do this o GitHub, I will post it if I can locate it)

Comment: @Titan you are probably right i thought you might be able to conditionally do that and retun never but that is a run time check i think

Comment: I think the issue in question is about [block-scoped type assertions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10421)?